# How to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP header for images on my server?

Tags: php, http

I'm trying to use my application to load images from my server, but I couldn't do it, as I do not know where to set **HTTP header:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *** for images. I have only basic knowledge on web programming, so its quite confusing what I get from the web.. Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You generally don't need this header for images, only for data that's accessed using AJAX. But if you need it, the proper way is with the `header()` function:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

This has to be done before your script produces any output, so it should generally be at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Thanks for replying, if I don't need this header for images, what do you think is wrong with it? As my application really cannot load the image..

Comment: How are you loading the images? What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm using Construct 2 to build my app, I had not received any error from my app, so I assume there must be something wrong with the server I registered on 000webhost.com.

Comment: If you're seeing broken image icons, there should be errors in the Javascript console.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was to include a file named .htaccess (notice the leading dot) anywhere in the path of the requested file, that file should contain this line:

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

The .htaccess can be place anywhere you like as long as its under /public_html